# Selenium / Select Dropdrown / assert that a certain value is present or not

Tags: java, selenium

I have two Select webelements. The first one is depending on the second one. For example: If you chose `interestPeriod` with value `20`, `loanTermSelect` does not offer the value `10`. And that is exactly what I want to check with a selenium webtest.

My code:

```
@Test
public void testLoanTerm20() {
    kqcPage = loginToFinancialPlanet().openKonditionenQuickcheckPage();
    kqcPage = kqcPage.fillForm(getLoanTerm20());
}

private Map<String, Object> getLoanTerm20() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("addTypeOfLoan", "KfW Energieeff. Bauen (153)");
    map.put("interestPeriod", "20");
    map.put("loanTermSelect", "25");
    return map;
}
```

Usually I'm using something like the following code to assert, that a given element is visible. But this time I want to check, if a given element offers a specific value.

```
assertThat(extranetRulesVersionDisplayBegriffMultiSumme.getButtonDelete().isDisplayed(), is(true));
```

What's the best practise? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: You can get the `text` of a particular `WebElement` and then you can put the condition during `String Comparison`. Whats the issue here?

Comment: the issue is, that i haven't done that before... but yes. it sound logical... do you have a code example for me that can be executed as JUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the options inside a `Select` class you can use:-

```
Select select = new Select(driver);
List<WebElement> allOptions = select.getOptions();
```

It will return a list of all the options inside the dropdown then you can iterate on the dropdown for fetching the text.

```
for(WebElement el : allOptions) {
    // So you can get the text like:-
    String text = el.getText();
    if(text.equals("specific value")) {
        // Your operation that you want to do once string matches.
    }
}
```

This way you can match the specific value you are looking for.

Hope it helps!

Comment: problem i face is, that `new Select(driver)` is red underlined. it suggests me to change visibility of `driver` to protected. what can't be right...

Comment: and what i'm askin myself = in the for loop. what tells the loop that i want to seach the `loanTermSelect` element?

Comment: ok join this chatroom lets discuss here :- http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109547/36715708